# XML / XSLT - XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: html, xml, xslt

When i open the xml file with mozilla i get this error:

XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: file:///D:/PTI/xsl.xsl
Line Number 26, Column 8:
-------^

How can i fix that ?

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>
  <books name="List">
    <book>
      <title>Don Quixote</title>
      <author>Miguel de Cervantes</author>
      <theme>Adventure</theme>
      <price>$120</price>
      <year>1605</year>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title>A Tale Of Two Cities</title>
      <author>Charles Dickens</author>
      <theme>History</theme>
      <price>$75</price>
      <year>1859</year>
    </book>
  </books>
```

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Book Catalog</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Theme</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="theme"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you forget to include a part of your XSLT file you're missing some closing tags (`template` and `stylesheet`). Just add them to the end of your `xsl.xsl` document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        ...your stuff here...
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```